# Как в Linux отделить место для Windows

Tags: linux, windows, gparted

У меня установлена система Linux. Хочу установить вторую OC - Windows.
Как правильно отделить место под OC Windows.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: откусить кусок от диска? от /home ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator а как это делается?

Comment: чтобы много не писать - читай тут http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Можно установить Windows на виртуалку (VirtualBox например), чтобы не мучать/мучаться с ЖД.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, но вроде единственный вариант - откусить часть от /dev/sdb5